# Merging multiple SpatialPolygonDataFrames in R when number of columns do not match

Tags: r, merge

I would like to merge multiple `SpatialPolygonDataFrame`s into one.
For Belgium & the Netherlands this works OK using `maptools`' `spRbind`:

```
td <- tempdir()
bel <- getData("GADM", country="BEL", level=1, path=td)
nld <- getData("GADM", country="NLD", level=1, path=td)
row.names(nld) <- paste("nld", row.names(nld), sep="_")
row.names(bel) <- paste("bel", row.names(bel), sep="_")
library(maptools)
bel_nld <- spRbind(bel, nld)
plot(bel_nld)
```

However, in my case I would like to merge the province outlines for both Belgium & the Netherlands, ie

```
td <- tempdir()
bel <- getData("GADM", country="BEL", level=2, path=td)
nld <- getData("GADM", country="NLD", level=1, path=td)
row.names(nld) <- paste("nld", row.names(nld), sep="_")
row.names(bel) <- paste("bel", row.names(bel), sep="_")
library(maptools)
bel_nld <- spRbind(bel, nld)
plot(bel_nld)
```

but then I get the error message "Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match"

Would anybody know how to resolve this, and obtain the provincial outlines of Belgium & the Netherlands in one `SpatialPolygonDataFrame`?

Comment: What attributes do you want in your merged dataset? `nld` only has names up to level 1, but `bel` has level 1 and level 2 names. If you just want a name for each region, drop all the other columns and create two spdfs with a `name` column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop all the attributes except the unique name. Keep other ones if you want, just make sure you have the same number in each:

```
> bel = bel[,"NAME_2"]
> nld = nld[,"NAME_1"]
```

You can't `spRbind` if the names are different so make them the same:

```
> names(bel)="NAME"
> names(nld)="NAME"
```

If you've kept the country code as well in the first step then `names(bel)=c("COUNTRY","NAME")` might be needed.

Once that's done:

```
> belnld = spRbind(bel, nld)
```

If you want to keep *all* the attributes of each country, then you probably need to construct two spdfs with all the attributes, filling in NA where one column doesn't exist in the other data set.

Comment: Many thanks! That did the trick (after making the province names unique)!